# Pandas groupby drop top 5% and bottom 5% of data

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Month   Col2
A       4
A       5
A       6
A       7
A       8
B       14
B       15
B       16
B       17
B       18
B       19
B       20
B       21
B       22
B       23
```

I want to get the following:

```
Month   Col2
A       5
A       6
A       7
B       16
B       17
B       18
B       19
B       20
B       21
```

In the above for group A, top 1 and bottom 1 was removed as they are each 5% total number of A (5).

In the above for group B, top 2 and bottom 2 was removed as they are each 5% of total number of B (10).

I am not sure how to achieve the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `GroupBy.apply`:

```
def crop(gr):
    gr_len = len(gr)
    amt = gr_len // 5
    return gr.iloc[amt: -amt]

df.groupby("Month", group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(crop)
```

where `crop` function finds the cropping amount as the 1/5 of the total length of the group and slices with `iloc` from start and end,

to get

```
   Month  Col2
1      A     5
2      A     6
3      A     7
7      B    16
8      B    17
9      B    18
10     B    19
11     B    20
12     B    21
```

(`group_keys` is `False` to get rid of extra index of grouper `Month` in the result; `sort` is `False` to keep the original order of appearance of the grouper column.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may mean you are dropping the top and bottom *10%* of each group.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'B', 8: 'B', 9: 'B', 10: 'B', 11: 'B', 12: 'B', 13: 'B', 14: 'B'}, 'Col2': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 8, 5: 14, 6: 15, 7: 16, 8: 17, 9: 18, 10: 19, 11: 20, 12: 21, 13: 22, 14: 23}})
pct = .1
for i, g in df.groupby('Month'):
    count = g.size
    drop = int(pct*count)
    # not necessary but helpful to see what's happening, if desired
    print(f'dropping top and bottom {pct:0.0%} of {count} obs. for group {i} ({count} obs)')
    df.drop(g['Col2'].nlargest(drop).index, inplace=True)
    df.drop(g['Col2'].nsmallest(drop).index, inplace=True)
```

yielding

```
   Month  Col2
1      A     5
2      A     6
3      A     7
7      B    16
8      B    17
9      B    18
10     B    19
11     B    20
12     B    21
```

Comment: i think it's one fifth of the length i.e. 20% if you will. 10% worked the same because `size` returns the total number of elements in the group which happens to have 2 columns so 10% * 2 = 20%.